# PASSENGER/RVM permission denied (13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, passenger

Hi all I am trying to run my test rails app using rvm & passenger

`passenger ruby` is set to `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.0/`

however I get the error below[image: passenger permission denied error]

When I check my rvm ruby wrapper I saw all files under ruby-2.2.0 which is what I am using, don't have any permissions(see image)

[image: file permession]

does anyone encounter the same thing. How can I solve this? I already tried `chmod 777 -R wrappers`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure `/usr/local/rvm` is world readable with:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/rvm
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer, My solution was I migrated to Unicorn + Rbenv + Capistrano setup

Answer (score 0):

try use set config PassengerUser https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengeruser . Set it with user that you use when install rvm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with apache and Passenger Ruby. In my case, my virtualhost was pointing to:
`PassengerRuby /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/wrappers/`

instead of:

`PassengerRuby /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/wrappers/ruby`